# Input Validation Do While loop

Tags: java, validation, input

I need to create a do while loop that works for text input that returns the user back to the loop. Currently it just display an error message if an input like "zero" is entered.

```
 do {
    System.out.println("Enter wall height (feet): ");
    wallHeight = scnr.nextDouble();
    } while (wallHeight <= 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code may work for you..

```
do {
      System.out.println("Enter wall height (feet): ");
      String text = scnr.nextLine();
      try {
          wallHeight = Double.valueOf(text);
      } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
          wallHeight=-1d;
      }
 } while (wallHeight <= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve here. As per your code now the loop will only work if the input is 0 or less. so if you enter a hight more than 0 e.g. 10, it will exit the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to java and am still learning terminology. I need the code to loop back with any invalid input like 0, "zero", "thirty", etc

Comment: I guess you only want to read numbers greater than 0 right? If the user enters invalid input you want to prompt the user again?

Comment: Yes I want numbers greater than zero and no text input. The only input that should break the loop is > 0